# while running app from xcode push notification is working but when install ipa it is not working

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, apple-push-notifications

I am developing a iOS app with push notification and it is working fine while running via xcode with device.But i try to generate ipa and install it is not working.(Notification sent from backend server,there device token not generated for ipa).The code I used to register push notification.

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
   - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{


NSString *tokenStr = [[[[deviceToken description]
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""]
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

NSLog(@"Device Token (raw): %@", deviceToken);
NSLog(@"Device Token (string): %@", tokenStr);

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userDefaults setObject:tokenStr forKey:@"deviceToken"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

}

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
 {
  [MSTLog printdebug:@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error];

 }
```

I'm using xcode 6.1.

Answer (score 3):

Two things to look at:

- the provisioning profile doesn't include a production push certificate (a sandbox cert is used when running via Xcode)
- ensure the call is being made to the APNS production (i.e. gateway.push.apple.com and not gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com)

Answer (score 1):

XCode 7.1 and above if you select Adhoc deployment the iPA is signed with distribution so the ipa installation will not receive notification while the same will receive when installed through XCode.

The solution is to use **save for development deployment** while exporting The resulting ipa will receive notification through sandbox on development certificate and provisioning 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check a provision profile when generating ipa and be sure that your certificate and a certificate at server side matched.

Your provision profile should be configured for push notification. Check it [here](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action)

[image]

Comment: Yes,I enabled push notifications